# Use webform to run powershell script on client side

Tags: c#, powershell, webforms

I'm trying to build a webform using C# that will run a powershell script on the client side then return the results back to the webform. The reason I wish to do this is because for me to able to successfully run the powershell script is to be able to use firewall authentication which doesn't have an API and needs actual human intervention to type user and password therefore i can't do everything on the server side.

overall, i want to leave the script on the server, but be able to 'send' the script and execute it from within client pc, then returning the values back to the server to populate the webform

Comment: have you done a google search or tried anything on your own.. there are actually lots of examples out there on the web here's a site you can read [How to run PowerShell Scripts for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)

Comment: yep i've tried to, but most of them as i have been able to find don't actually give u an example on how to fully automate the solution. I know i can leave the script to the client side and then just ask the webform to run it but isn't it that a little insecure, that's why i'm looking something that stays 100% on server side

Comment: @DJKRAZE - it is not going to help efx because browsers simply will not allow to run any external code on client side. This simply can not be done without installing your custom program on client machines.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write java applet or ActiveX. In it you run powershell script and pass data to form using JavaScript. But you have to read about security, collecting data for selected technology.